# Calculating a row position in the table

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Let's say I have a table like this (this is just a simplified example, the real table I'm talking about is much more complex):

```
CREATE TABLE media (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
description TEXT NOT NULL,
voted INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
rating FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

The *voted* column represents a number of votes the item has received and the *rating* column represents the total rating of the item.

Now, what I want to do is select a single item from the table based on id, something like:

```
SELECT m.* FROM media AS m WHERE id = 5;
```

But, in addition, I want to calculate the position of this row based on the *rating* column and fetch that as an additional column, let's say called a site_rank (so the bigger the rating of the row is the higher its site_rank will be, I hope I explained it well). My guess is this can be achieved with a subselect query but I'm not sure how to do it.

Any help?

Comment: Might I suggest implementing a Site_Rank Column that gets updated every so often? Probably would be much easier.

Comment: That way you do one really big database call (or a few smaller ones), and then update each one. And then you don't need to do anything else for like 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM media WHERE rating > (SELECT rating FROM media WHERE id = 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will output high `rank` for most voted media.

If you want low rank for the most voted (like, the most voted gets the `rank` of `1`), just reverse the sign in the subquery.

```
SELECT  mo.*,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    media mi
        WHERE   (mi.rating, mi.id) <= (mo.rating, mo.id)
        ) AS rank
FROM    media mo
WHERE   mo.id = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    m1.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM media AS m2 WHERE m2.rating > m1.rating) AS site_rank
FROM
    media AS m1
WHERE
    id = 5;
```

Note that this does not define a complete ordering because there might be items with equal rating and they will report the same site rank.

Answer (score 1):

Does MySQL support the standard SQL rank() function? It does exactly what you want.

```
select
  *,
  rank() over (
    order by rating desc
  ) as site_rank
from media
```